# Splitting classes into different .cpp files

Tags: c++

How would I go about splitting these classes into different .cpp files? The program is meant to simulate a dog parlor that gets a dog's name, age, it's owners name (if it has an owner) and store them into an array of object pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Citizen{
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        Citizen(string name){
            this->name = name;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        string getAddress(){
            return address;
        }
        
        void setName(string name){
            this->name = name;
        }
};

class Animal{
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
        Citizen* owner;
    public:
        Animal(string name, int age, Citizen* owner){
            this->name = name;
            this->age = age;
            this->owner = owner;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        int getAge(){
            return age;
        }
        Citizen* getCitizen(){
            return owner;
        }
        void setName(string name){
            this->name = name;
        }
        void setAge(int age){
            this->age = age;
        }
        void setCitizen(Citizen* owner){
            this->owner = owner;
        }
};

void swapNames(Animal* a1, Animal* a2){
    string temp = a1->getName();
    a1->setName(a2->getName());
    a2->setName(temp);
}

int main(){
    Animal* animals[10];
    int numAnimals = 0;
    int choice;
    string name;
    int age;
    string ownerName;
    string hasOwner;
    string firstName;
    string secondName;
    bool foundFirst = false;
    bool foundSecond = false;
    Animal* firstAnimal;
    Animal* secondAnimal;
    do{
        cout << "Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 1){
            cout << "Please enter the name of the dog: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Please enter the age: ";
            cin >> age;
            cout << "Does the dog have an owner: ";
            cin >> hasOwner;
            
            //in case of yes take owner's name else don't take

            //compare hasOwner value with string "Yes" || "yes" || "y" || "Y"
            if(hasOwner == "Yes" || hasOwner == "yes" || hasOwner == "y" || hasOwner == "Y"){
                cout << "Please enter the owners name: ";
                cin >> ownerName;
                cout << "Please enter the address: ";
                cin >> address;
                Citizen* owner = new Citizen(ownerName);
                animals[numAnimals] = new Animal(name, age, owner);
            }
            else{
                animals[numAnimals] = new Animal(name, age, NULL);
            }
            numAnimals++;
            cout << "The list of dogs are as follows: ";
            for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++){
                cout << animals[i]->getName() << " (Owner: ";
                if(animals[i]->getCitizen() == NULL){
                    cout << "hoping for adoption)";
                }
                else{
                    cout << animals[i]->getCitizen()->getName() << ")";
                }
                if(i != numAnimals - 1){
                    cout << ", ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if(choice == 2){
            cout << "Enter name of first dog: ";
            cin >> firstName;
            cout << "Enter name of second dog: ";
            cin >> secondName;
            for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++){
                if(animals[i]->getName() == firstName){
                    firstAnimal = animals[i];
                    foundFirst = true;
                }
                if(animals[i]->getName() == secondName){
                    secondAnimal = animals[i];
                    foundSecond = true;
                }
            }
            if(foundFirst && foundSecond){
                swapNames(firstAnimal, secondAnimal);
                cout << "The list of dogs are as follows: ";
                for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++){
                    cout << animals[i]->getName() << " (Owner: ";
                    if(animals[i]->getCitizen() == NULL){
                        cout << "hoping for adoption)";
                    }
                    else{
                        cout << animals[i]->getCitizen()->getName() << ")";
                    }
                    if(i != numAnimals - 1){
                        cout << ", ";
                    }
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "No dog found" << endl;
            }
        }
    }while(choice != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is given in the citizen.cpp file:

```
#include "citizen.h"

Citizen::Citizen() {
    
    
}

Citizen::~Citizen() {

}
```

And here's an example of the output:

```
Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: 1
Please enter the name of the dog: Jake
Please enter the age: 12
Does the dog have an owner: Yes
Please enter the owners name: Steve
Please enter the address: Brooklyn
The list of dogs are as follows: Jake(Owner: Steve)
Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: 1
Please enter the name of the dog: John
Please enter the age: 4
Does the dog have an owner: No
The list of dogs are as follows: Jake(Owner: Steve), John(Owner: hoping for adoption)
Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: 1
Please enter the name of the dog: Lemon
Please enter the age: 9
Does the dog have an owner: Yes
Please enter the owners name: Craig
Please enter the address: Brooklyn
The list of dogs are as follows: Jake(Owner: Steve), John(Owner: hoping for adoption)
,Lemon(Owner: Craig)
Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: 2
Enter name of first dog: Jake
Enter name of second dog: Lemon
The list of dogs are as follows: Lemon(Owner: Steve),
John(Owner: hoping for adoption), Jake(Owner: Craig)
Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: 3
```

I'm just having a bit of a hard time figuring this out so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What you don't understand is how to split declaration/definition, or how to include files into others ?

Comment: If im being honest it's both

Answer (score 0):

You can create two header files `citizen.h` and `animal.h`, move the definition of `class Citizen` into `citizen.h` and move the definition of `class Animal` to `animal.h`, and replace these definitions with `#include "citizen.h"` and `#include "animal.h"`. Ideally, you should also add [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to both header files. Both header files should also have the line `#include <string>`, because they are using `std::string`. Also, `animals.h` should `#include "citizen.h"`, because it requires the declaration of `class Citizen`.

It is generally not advisable to use `using namespace std;` in header files, so you should add `std::` were necessary in the header files. See this question for further information:

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/12149471)

After doing that, you can create two new source files `citizen.cpp` and `animal.cpp` and move all function definitions from the header to the corresponding source file, converting the function definitions to function declarations in the header file. Each source file should also `#include` its corresponding header file.

After doing this, your files should have the following content:

citizen.h

```
#ifndef CITIZEN_H_INCLUDED
#define CITIZEN_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Citizen{
    private:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Citizen( std::string name );
        std::string getName();
        std::string getAddress();
        void setName( std::string name );
};

#endif
```

animals.h

```
#ifndef ANIMALS_H_INCLUDED
#define ANIMALS_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

#include "citizen.h"

class Animal{
    private:
        std::string name;
        int age;
        Citizen* owner;
    public:
        Animal( std::string name, int age, Citizen* owner );
        std::string getName();
        int getAge();
        Citizen* getCitizen();
        void setName( std::string name );
        void setAge( int age );
        void setCitizen( Citizen* owner);
};

#endif
```

citizen.cpp

```
#include "citizen.h"

Citizen::Citizen( std::string name ) {
    this->name = name;
}

std::string Citizen::getName() {
    return name;
}

std::string Citizen::getAddress() {
    return address;
}
        
void Citizen::setName( std::string name ) {
    this->name = name;
}
```

animal.cpp

```
#include "animal.h"

Animal::Animal( std::string name, int age, Citizen* owner) {
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
    this->owner = owner;
}

std::string Animal::getName() {
    return name;
}

int Animal::getAge() {
    return age;
}

Citizen* Animal::getCitizen() {
    return owner;
}

void Animal::setName( std::string name ) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Animal::setAge(int age) {
    this->age = age;
}

void Animal::setCitizen( Citizen* owner ) {
    this->owner = owner;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#include "citizen.h"
#include "animal.h"

using namespace std;

void swapNames(Animal* a1, Animal* a2) {
    string temp = a1->getName();
    a1->setName(a2->getName());
    a2->setName(temp);
}

int main() {
    Animal* animals[10];
    int numAnimals = 0;
    int choice;
    string name;
    int age;
    string ownerName;
    string hasOwner;
    string firstName;
    string secondName;
    bool foundFirst = false;
    bool foundSecond = false;
    Animal* firstAnimal;
    Animal* secondAnimal;
    do {
        cout << "Enter 1 to add a dog, 2 to swap names or 3 to stop: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 1) {
            cout << "Please enter the name of the dog: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Please enter the age: ";
            cin >> age;
            cout << "Does the dog have an owner: ";
            cin >> hasOwner;
            
            //in case of yes take owner's name else don't take

            //compare hasOwner value with string "Yes" || "yes" || "y" || "Y"
            if(hasOwner == "Yes" || hasOwner == "yes" || hasOwner == "y" || hasOwner == "Y") {
                cout << "Please enter the owners name: ";
                cin >> ownerName;
                cout << "Please enter the address: ";
                cin >> address;
                Citizen* owner = new Citizen(ownerName);
                animals[numAnimals] = new Animal(name, age, owner);
            }
            else {
                animals[numAnimals] = new Animal(name, age, NULL);
            }
            numAnimals++;
            cout << "The list of dogs are as follows: ";
            for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++) {
                cout << animals[i]->getName() << " (Owner: ";
                if(animals[i]->getCitizen() == NULL) {
                    cout << "hoping for adoption)";
                }
                else {
                    cout << animals[i]->getCitizen()->getName() << ")";
                }
                if(i != numAnimals - 1) {
                    cout << ", ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if(choice == 2) {
            cout << "Enter name of first dog: ";
            cin >> firstName;
            cout << "Enter name of second dog: ";
            cin >> secondName;
            for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++) {
                if(animals[i]->getName() == firstName) {
                    firstAnimal = animals[i];
                    foundFirst = true;
                }
                if(animals[i]->getName() == secondName) {
                    secondAnimal = animals[i];
                    foundSecond = true;
                }
            }
            if(foundFirst && foundSecond) {
                swapNames(firstAnimal, secondAnimal);
                cout << "The list of dogs are as follows: ";
                for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++){
                    cout << animals[i]->getName() << " (Owner: ";
                    if(animals[i]->getCitizen() == NULL) {
                        cout << "hoping for adoption)";
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << animals[i]->getCitizen()->getName() << ")";
                    }
                    if(i != numAnimals - 1) {
                        cout << ", ";
                    }
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "No dog found" << endl;
            }
        }
    } while(choice != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above will not compile, for the same reason that your original code does not compile (`address` is not declared).

Comment: I would advise to use `#include "citizen.h"` instead of `#include <citizen.h>` when including personal/local headers

Comment: @Ladislus: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I had written it correctly in the code, but written it wrongly in the explanation. I believe I have fixed it now.